# Is there a way to make a graphql query once without rendering?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I have a react app that I need to make GraphQL queries to an endpoint in order to get data. The data doesn't change during the lifetime of the app. So I would like to make the query when the component mounts, and store the data.

I've tried making the Query call in the `ComponentDidMount` method, but it doesn't work, I BELIEVE, because I need to render the results. The truth is, I'm very new to these frameworks and libraries and am not sure how some/most of it works. I want to believe that I'm mistaken and there is some way to store data from a query without needing to render it... but I can't seem to figure it out :(

Can anyone help me out? Point me in a direction, or correct my probably wrong assumptions about the issue I'm facing?

Comment: just use graphql HOC query

Comment: Look into ``react-apollo's`` ```graphql()``` and ```compose``` functions https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo/#graphqlquery-configcomponent.

Answer (score 0):

With `react-apollo` you could do it like [this](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/apollo-client/#ApolloClient.query):

```
import { withApollo } from 'react-apollo'

class SomeComponent extends Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    const result = await this.props.client.query({
      query: GRAPHQL_QUERY,
      variables: QUERY_VARIABLES
    })
    // do something with result
  }
}

export default withApollo(SomeComponent)
```